# ¿Como seleccionar varias líneas en Netbeans 8.2?

Tags: netbeans

En algunos editores de texto como Sublime Text, Atom o Brackets se puede seleccionar más de una sola línea con el puntero, y así escribir en varios lugares al mismo tiempo, la verdad es bastante cómodo, tenía la duda si era posible hacer eso con netbeans, instalando algún plugin o moviendo algo en la configuración?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solo mantén presionado `CTRL+SHIFT` y has click sobre las posiciones donde quieres ubicar el puntero.